# mongodb nodejs asking a question regarding find method and nested objects in apis

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api

i have two sets of data in mongodb database both ahave one similar field as author_id
so i have to check a conditon from one set and then pick the id from there and then see the id that matches in second set and print that but i am getting empty object

```
 const Pricesoff = async (req,res) =>{
     let abc = await BookModel.find( { price : { $gte: 50, $lte: 100} }) 
     //.select({author_id:1})
    
     let xyz = abc.author_id
     let obj = await authormodel.find({author_id: xyz})
     let newo = {
         "authorname":obj.author_name
     }
         res.send(newo)
}
```

Comment: `find()` returns a cursor but you are treating it as if it returned the document. You either want `findOne()` or to iterate the cursor processing each of the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it might be as @user20042973 mentioned the .find() returns a cursor
you might want to use findOne or add .lean() to find()
check these urls they might help
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html#using-lean

the code is going to be something like this

```
 let abc = await BookModel.find( { price : { $gte: 50, $lte: 100} }).lean()
 //.select({author_id:1})

 let xyz = abc.author_id
 let obj = await authormodel.find({author_id: xyz}).lean()
 let newo = {
     "authorname":obj.author_name
 }
res.send(newo)
```